# Extend a Scrapy ItemLoader with custom methods

Tags: python, scrapy

The Scrapy documentation lists all [the built-in methods of ItemLoader instances](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#itemloader-objects) and explains [how to declare your own Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-item-loaders). However, any ItemLoaders you declare will apply to all processed items. You can modify their behavior a little with [Item Loader Contexts](http://lists%20all%20[the%20built-in%20methods%20of%20ItemLoader%20instances][2].), but this is frequently not granular enough.

Suppose I have a Scrapy project where the spiders and items all inherit the same base spider and item loaders, but the spiders all contain site-specific logic with a handful of common functions. Nowhere in the Scrapy documentation do I find mention of adding class methods to ItemLoaders so that instead of:

```
import mymodule

class MySpider(BaseSpiderName):
  def parse_item(self, response):
    product = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    new_value = mymodule.myfunction(argument, ..., ...)
    product.add_value('my_field', new_value)
```

You could write:

```
# (no extra import)
class MySpider(BaseSpiderName):
  def parse_item(self, response):
    product = CustomItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    product.custom_function(argument, ..., ...)
```

Even though this seems like an obvious way to extend ItemLoaders like you would for any other class, it's not documented and I don't see examples of how to do this in Scrapy anywhere I've checked (Google, StackOverflow). Is it possible/supported, and how would you declare them?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible/supported, and how would you declare them?

It is possible. Which way to do it depends on the type of logic you are sharing.

You can declare your methods in a Scrapy-agnostic way, i.e. as you would do with any other Python class: subclass your `CustomItemLoader` class and define the method in that subclass:

```py
from scrapy.loaders import ItemLoader

class CustomItemLoader(ItemLoader):

    def custom_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.add_value('my_field', mymodule.myfunction(*args, **kwargs))
```

Alternatively, depending on the actual logic that you have in that function shared by *some* spiders, a simple [processor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors) that you pass to your `add_*` methods might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `CustomItemLoader` class in `items.py` file where you defined your `Product` item as below:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, TakeFirst

class CustomItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    
    def custom_function(argument1, argument2, argument3):
        # your custom function logic goes here..
        pass


class Product(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    pass
```

Then you can use `CustomItemLoader` in your spider code.. something like this:

```
from <PROJECT-NAME>.items import CustomItemLoader, Product

class MySpider(BaseSpiderName):
   def parse_item(self, response):
      product = CustomItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
      product.custom_function(argument, ..., ...)
```